# Ubuntu 12.04 Cloud Images Hang on First Boot in Virtualbox

Tags: 12.04, virtualbox, virtualbox-networking, vagrant, cloud-init

I've run across an annoying bug with the recent official builds of Precise (both 32 and 64 bit versions) for virtualbox found here:
http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/vagrant/precise/current/

When these images are booted up the first time they will perpetually hang while booting.

Here's how to replicate the issue:

```
vagrant box add precise64-current http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/vagrant/precise/current/precise-server-cloudimg-amd64-vagrant-disk1.box
vagrant init precise64-current
vagrant up
```

Now it will start up the server but fail to connect until you do the following...

```
vagrant halt -f
vagrant up
```

...and now it will work just fine

To research this oddity I enabled the virtualbox gui in my Vagrantfile and tried it again. On first boot, it appears to load the GRUB bootloader and then freeze as soon as it attempts to load ubuntu in non-recovery mode.  Every boot thereafter works just fine.

I have replicated this on two machines (both hosts are OSX machines).

Is there anything that can be done to debug this issue or some virtualbox setting that will fix it?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I assumed the images hosted at cloud-images.ubuntu.com were maintained by canonical?

Comment: They are but in case the images are buggy there is not much we can do here at AU.#

Comment: What would be an appropriate channel to contact those who can do something about it?

Comment: I have a similar problem. Did you get it solved? If yes, then how?

Comment: never solved it. I just ended up creating my own images with [packer](https://www.packer.io)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried running the following in the directory of your Vagrantfile after running the `vagrant init` but before running the `vagrant up` commands:

```
vagrant plugin install vagrant-vbguest
```

This worked for me, at least with the most recent Trusty Tahr cloud image.

Comment: unfortunately this does not work for me...  The Trusty Tahr (14.04) cloud image doesn't exhibit the problems described in the original question, but the Precise 12.04 image does.  The problem doesn't have to do with a missing our outdated virtualbox additions, the problem is the box is inaccessible on first boot.

Comment: Sorry to hear this didn't help. I haven't tried using Vagrant with the particular image you're talking about. Now that 14.04 is out, and given it's an LTS release, do you have the option of moving from 12.04 to it?

Comment: I intend to use the image with AWS OpsWorks and mirror it with Vagrant.  Unfortunately OpsWorks doesn't support 14.04 yet but hopefully that will change soon.